# How can I create a (None,299,299,3) from (299,299,3)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-2

I am trying to use the Keras 2 incepctionV3 based trained model to predict an image for testing purpose. My original model work well, then I try to create a model with specified input_shape (299,299,3)

```
base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(299,299,3))
```

The training process looks fine but when I try to use it to predict the image it causes this error.

> ValueError: Error when checking : expected input_1 to have shape
>   (None, 299, 299, 3) but got array with shape (1, 229, 229, 3)

```
    import sys
    import argparse
    import numpy as np
    from PIL import Image
    from io import BytesIO

    from keras.preprocessing import image
    from keras.models import load_model
    from keras.applications.inception_v3 import preprocess_input


    target_size = (229, 229) #fixed size for InceptionV3 architecture


    def predict(model, img, target_size):
      """Run model prediction on image
      Args:
        model: keras model
        img: PIL format image
        target_size: (w,h) tuple
      Returns:
        list of predicted labels and their probabilities
      """
      if img.size != target_size:
        img = img.resize(target_size)

      x = image.img_to_array(img)
      print(x.shape)
      print("model input",model.inputs)
      print("model output",model.outputs)
      x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
      #x = x[None,:,:,:]
      print(x.shape)
      x = preprocess_input(x)

      print(x.shape)
      preds = model.predict(x)
      print('Predicted:',preds)
      return preds[0]
```

Here is the print out

```
(229, 229, 3)  
('model input', [<tf.Tensor 'input_1:0' shape=(?, 299, 299, 3) dtype=float32>])  
('model output', [<tf.Tensor 'dense_2/Softmax:0' shape=(?, 5) dtype=float32>]) 
(1, 229, 229, 3) 
(1, 229, 229, 3)
```

(1,299,299,3) mean 1 image in 299 X 299 with 3 channel. 
What is the expected input of my trained model (None,299,299,3) meaning in this case? How can I create a (None,299,299,3) from (299,299,3)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here the problem is image size, set the require size to `299, 299`

```
target_size = (299, 299) #fixed size for InceptionV3 architecture
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
preds = model.predict(x, batch_size=1)
```

batch_size=32 by default. And you have only one image to predict on.
(None,299,299,3) meaning in this case that model.predict expects array with shape (n,299,299,3) with n > batch_size to process it batch by batch and return (n, outputs_dim) dimensional array of predictions.